# How do I convert a rotation matrix into the correct quaternion for particle rotation?

Tags: particles, quaternion

I'm trying to render fractals using a particle system. [image: Fractal example]

I generated the one on the left using graphics programming. The one on the right is rendered using a particle system. The rotation matrix conversion results in the expected quaternions but the particle system interprets them in a different way. I don't know how to offset this difference. I tried a lot of things like swamping and inverting axis. for some examples it works but I haven't found a solution to convert the rotation matrix to quaternions for the particle system consistently.

This is the code I currently use to calculate the quaternion.

```
def rot2Quat(M1):
    r = np.math.sqrt(float(1)+M1[0,0]+M1[1,1]+M1[2,2])*0.5
    i = (M1[2,1]-M1[1,2])/(4*r)
    j = (M1[0,2]-M1[2,0])/(4*r)
    k = (M1[1,0]-M1[0,1])/(4*r)
    return(i,j,k,r)
```

After some testing I found that setting the particle rotation to (0.71,0.0,0.0,0.71) results in the original orientation of the object. I don't know why this isn't (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0). This is the best clue I found so far.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code to

```
def rot2Quat(M1):
   r = np.math.sqrt(float(1)+M1[0,0]+M1[1,1]+M1[2,2])*0.5
   i = (M1[2,1]-M1[1,2])/(4*r)
   j = (M1[0,2]-M1[2,0])/(4*r)
   k = (M1[1,0]-M1[0,1])/(4*r)
   return(k,-j,i,r)
```

The quaternion is formatted in Z,Y,X,W format I'm not sure why I had to invert the Y (this could be a bug in another part of my code).

And I multiplied the final quaternion with (0.7071,0.0,0.0,-0.7071).

```
quaternion_multiply( rot2Quat(rotMatrix),(0.7071,0.0,0.0,-0.7071))
```

This solved my problem.